# Why does using os.path.join with pygame/pyganim cause an error?

Tags: python, pygame, directory

So im trying to create a game using pygame and pyganim

I like using folders to sort my games files into scripts, images, animations, etc

For some reason if i use the os module and os.path.join to find the folder the files are in while trying to creating a animation object with pyganimation i get the error

```
      File "H:\Projects\Arcflash\Arcflash.py", line 35, in <module>
        Pyganim_Arcflash = pyganim.PygAnimation([(os.path.join("Images\Animation\Arcflash", 'Arcflash_001'))])
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyganim\__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
        frame = (frames[i][0], int(frames[i][1]))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'm'
```

This is a snippet of my current code

```
# Imports
import pygame
import os
import math
import pyganim
# -- Initialize the Surface --
# Startup
pygame.init()

# Screen
size = (500, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption = ("Images - Rewrite")
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# -- Assign Global Variables --
#Sets the color of pure white to a variable to be called
WHITE    = (255, 255, 255)
#Sets the color of pure black to a variable to be called
BLACK    = (0, 0, 0)
#Sets the background to an image
Menu_Background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "menu_background.png"))
#Sets the player to an image
Player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "player.png"))
#Sets the pointer to an image 
Pointer = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "pointer.png"))
#Sets the dark and bright menu go button to an image
Menu_Go_Dark = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "go_dark.png"))
Menu_Go_Bright = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "go_bright.png"))
#Sets the dark and bright menu exit button to an image
Menu_Exit_Dark = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "exit_dark.png"))
Menu_Exit_Bright = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images", "exit_bright.png"))
#Assigns all the Arcflash text frames to a list
Arcflash_list = [os.path.join("Images\Animation\Arcflash", "Arcflash_001.png"),
                 os.path.join("Images\Animation\Arcflash", "Arcflash_002.png"),
                 os.path.join("Images\Animation\Arcflash", "Arcflash_003.png"),
                 os.path.join("Images\Animation\Arcflash", "Arcflash_004.png"),
                 os.path.join("Images\Animation\Arcflash", "Arcflash_005.png"),
                 os.path.join("Images\Animation\Arcflash", "Arcflash_006.png")]
#Sets the pyganimation list up for the arcflash text
Anim_Arcflash = pyganim.PygAnimation([(Arcflash_list[0], 100), (Arcflash_list[1], 100), (Arcflash_list[2], 100), (Arcflash_list[3], 100), (Arcflash_list[4]), (Arcflash_list[5])])
```

My goal is to get pyganim to take the images while they are in the folder, instead i get the error.
help?

(This question may or may not be well formatted, im not comfortable with this website and my last questions havent been well received)

Edit 1: Just stuff that ive tried to fix this

1: Not using a list

2: placing the os.path.join in many diffirent locations based on where i would       think it would logically go

The only thing that seems to actually fix this error is not using folders, but that looks quite awful and im not interested in that approach. Id rather not use pyganim at all.

Comment: `frames[i][1]` is the string `'m'`. Presumably, `frames[i]` is some larger string.

Comment: I think it's because the PygAnimation constructor expects a list of tuples but you passed it two strings: `(Arcflash_list[4]), (Arcflash_list[5])`. You forgot to add integers for those frames, so when pygame attempts to get the integer from the tuple with `frames[i][1]` it indexes the string `Images\Animation\Arcflash\Arcflash_005.png` instead.

Comment: Is their anyway to possibly bypass this issue, id really rather not have to put all of my animations in the same folder as my script. it may sound stupid but im really careful with how i organize things.

Comment: this may be somewhat old but i realise i misread your answer, @Rawing you should post it as an answer so i can confirm. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the PygAnimation constructor expects a list of tuples but you passed it two strings: `(Arcflash_list[4]), (Arcflash_list[5])`. You forgot to add integers for those frames, so when pygame attempts to get the integer from the tuple with `frames[i][1]` it ends up indexing the string `Images\Animation\Arcflash\Arcflash_005.png` instead.